# House Nginx rewrite rules inside of project folder like htaccess files

Tags: nginx

Is there a way with Nginx to house rewrite rules inside of the projects folder like an htaccess file? I have been setting my rules inside the /etc/nginx/sites-available/??? configuration file.

I would like to track these rules inside of my Git repo for use across multiple vagrant enviorments, so is where a way to have a sub config file inside of the projects www directory?

Would I use a standard nginx include?

```
server {
  include /usr/share/nginx/html/???/rewrites.conf;
  ...
}
```

Is this bad practice(this is just for development environments)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact it's possible to do this.

You could include the specified file or folder (if you have rewrites for more projects) in the nginx configuration. As suggested by the OP this can be achieved by using include in the *server* block.

But you should **not** do this on a production machine! Everybody who got write access to the www folder can badly change your nginx config. This is because of the way nginx handles rewrites.

Nevertheless it might be fine for a dev environment that's not available to the public.